# In Ruby, how can the Regexp#~ unary operator be aliased?

Tags: regex, ruby, alias

Playing with the freedom that Ruby offers in its base features, I found rather easy to alias most operator used in the language, but [the Regexp#~ unary prefix operator](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_regexp.html#Regexp._eq_sd) is trickier.

A first naïve approach would be to alias it in the Regexp class itself

```
class Regexp
  alias hit ~@ # remember that @ stands for "prefix version"
  # Note that a simple `alias_method :hit, :~@` will give the same result 
end
```

As it was pointed in some answer bellow, this approach *is* somehow functionnal with the dot notation calling form, like `/needle/.hit`. However trying to execute `hit /needle/` will raise `undefined method` hit' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`

So an other naïve approach would be to define this very method in `Object`, something like

```
class Object
  def ~@(pattern)
    pattern =~ $_
  end
end
```

However, this won’t work, as the `$_` global variable is in fact locally binded and won’t keep the value it has in the calling context, that is `$_` is always `nil` in the previous snippet.

So the question is, is it possible to have the expression `hit /needle/` to restitute the same result as `~ /needle/`?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" and the specific version/environment; don't see any reason this wouldn't work like any other alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as the completed question now inhibits it, the main hindrance is the narrow scope of `$_`. That’s where [`trace_var`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-trace_var) can come to the rescue:

```
trace_var :$_, proc { |nub| 
  $last_explicitly_read_line = nub
  #puts "$_ is now '#{nub}'" 
}
  

def reach(pattern)
  $last_explicitly_read_line =~ pattern
end


def first
  $_ = "It’s needless to despair."
end

def second
  first
  p reach /needle/
  $_ = 'What a needlework!'
  p reach /needle/
end


p reach /needle/

second
p reach /needle/

$_ = nil
p reach /needle/
```

So the basic idea is to stash the value of `$_` each time it is changed in an other variable that will be accessible in other subsequent calling context. Here it was implemented with a an other global variable (not locally binded, unlike `$_` of course), but the same result could be obtained with other implementations, like defining a class variable on `Object`.

One could also try to use something like [binding_of_caller](https://rubygems.org/gems/binding_of_caller/versions/1.0.0) or [binding_ninja](https://rubygems.org/gems/binding_ninja), but my own approach of doing so failed, and also of course it comes with additional dependencies which have their own limitations.

Comment: For information, this is the approach retained in the Gem I was coding when I encountered this challenge: https://github.com/psychoslave/englishest

Answer (score 3):

Works just fine for me:

```ruby
class Regexp
  alias_method :hit, :~ # both of them work
  # alias hit ~         # both of them work
end

$_ = "input data"

/at/.hit #=> 7
~/at/    #=> 7
/at/.hit #=> 7
~/at/    #=> 7
```

Comment: Yes, this works, indeed. I also wanted `hit /at/` to work just like `~/at/`, but for this I’ll have to define a method, or catch a missing_method within the Object class I guess.